# Qt: Store a Tree (QTreeView + QStandardItemModel) in a Database Table

Tags: sql, qt, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel, qmodelindex

As you can see from the title, I use a QStandardItemModel to store a Tree Structure. I manipulate this structure inside a QTreeView, than I need to save it on a database in this format:

```
|id|Parent|Child |
| 1|      |ITEM01|
| 2|     1|ITEM02|
| 3|     2|ITEM03|
| 4|     3|ITEM04|
| 5|     4|ITEM05|
| 6|     5|ITEM06|
| 7|     6|ITEM07|
| 8|     3|ITEM08|
| 9|     3|ITEM09|
|10|     3|ITEM10|
```

That represent this structure:

```
ITEM01
 ║
 ╠═► ITEM02
 ║    ║
 ║    ╚═► ITEM03
 ║         ║
 ║         ╠═► ITEM04
 ║         ║    ║
 ║         ║    ╚═► ITEM05
 ║         ║         ║
 ║         ║         ╚═► ITEM06
 ║         ║              ║
 ║         ║              ╚═► ITEM07
 ║         ║
 ║         ╠═► ITEM08
 ║         ╠═► ITEM09
 ║         ╚═► ITEM10
```

in other words "id" represent uniquely a node, the field "parent" is a reference to the parent node. The root node is an empty field.

My question is: how to get an uniquely id (in int format), from QStandardItemModel?
I've tried with QModelIndex::row() and QPersistentModelIndex::row() but it seems not to be unique.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You could explain yourself better, your question confuses me, is your question to keep the QStandardItemModel in the database with that structure?

Comment: in your example where QModelIndex::row() and QPersistentModelIndex::row() are not unique?

Comment: Thank you for the interest in my question, I've find a solution with the suggestions by Kuba Ober. And sorry for the unclearness. In any case, my question was related to the way to export a tree structure from a QStandardItemModel to a database table, where the field "id" identify a node and the field "parent" is a self reference to the parent node. My first attemp was to get a unique identifier from QModelIndex::row(), but it is unique only for the rows under the same parent.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to assign the indices from an incrementing counter as you traverse the tree in a certain depth-first order, e.g. postorder - left...right, root.

If you store the `id` and `parent` as roles of your element, then:

```
int assignIdsPostorder(QStandardItem * e, int idRole, int parentRole, int counter = 0) {
  auto const N = e->rowCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    counter = assignIdsDFS(e->child(i), idRole, parentRole, counter);
  if (e->setData(counter, idRole)) counter++;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    e->child(i)->setData(e->data(idRole), parentRole);
  return counter;
}
```

A minor modification would accommodate storing the `id` and `parent` in individual columns.

If the indices don't need to be valid at all times, then you can generate them lazily with memoization (caching). A `QStandardItem`-derived element would reimplement `data()` to perform partial tree traversals to generate its `ids`. The order of traversal would need to be adapted to the properties of your tree if you'd want to avoid the case of potentially having to annotate the entire tree on a single id query.

Comment: Thank You! I didn't know the Qt roles. I'm new to Qt.